# Unknown column error produced by Doctrine Query Where clause

Tags: php, doctrine

I have the following query:

```
return Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('Model_Article m')
         ->where($where)
         ->orderBy($order);
```

In `$where` I have this:

```
$where='m.title='.$name;
```

The above produces this error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sadsa' in 'where clause'. Failing Query: "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM article a WHERE a.title = sadsa"
```

Why?

Comment: I think your query must be something like: "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM article a WHERE a.title = 'sadsa' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is because resulting query looks like "** where title=sadsda **", so SQL engine looks for column named "sadsda". To prevent it you must mention, that you want to compare with a string, not a column value. You can make it using your engine rules (usually enclose string with "'"), but it isn't secure, I think you should use placeholders engine, that doctrine provides, for example

```
$whereKey = 'm.title=?';
$whereValue = 'sadsda';
Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Model_Article m')->where($whereKey,$whereValue)->orderBy($order);
```